# How can use AutoMapper to map two collections of objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I try to use AutoMapper but when I what to map 2 collection I get an error.
These are my entity and dto classes that I want to use AutoMapper:

```
public class HeadQuarters
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string HeadQuartersName { get; set; }
    public string HeadQuartersCode { get; set; }
    public string HeadQuartersDescription { get; set; }        
    public bool IsActiv { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Adresa> Adresa { get; set; }      
}

public class HeadQuartersDTO
{
    public string HeadQuartersName { get; set; }
    public string HeadQuartersCode { get; set; }
    public string HeadQuartersDescription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AdresaDTO> Addresses { get; set; }        
    public EntityState Status { get; set; }
}
```

These are my entity and dto collection classes:

```
public class AdresaDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string StreetNr { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public string Entrance{ get; set; }
    public string Apartment{ get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }      
    public EntityState Status { get; set; }
}

public partial class Adresa
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string StreetNr { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public string Entrance{ get; set; }
    public string Apartment{ get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int? HeadQuartersId { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int? ContractPersonDataId { get; set; }
}
```

I write this code for to use AutoMapper:

```
public static HeadQuarters DtoToEntity(HeadQuartersDTO dto)
{
    var mapper = new Mapper(MapperConfiguration());            
    return  mapper.Map<HeadQuarters>(dto);            
}

private static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration()
{
    return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<HeadQuartersDTO, HeadQuarters>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Adresa, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Addresses)));
}
```

But when I add some in collection I get an error. This is the error message that I get:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get.

Comment: what error you're getting?

Comment: You need to add configuration to handle mapping to IsActiv  and Id properties. Additionally, you need to configure mapping from AdresaDTO to Adresa. If you show how you want those to map, I can show you how to configure AutoMapper properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you’re trying to do, you should be able to update your code like this:

```
public static HeadQuarters DtoToEntity(HeadQuartersDTO dto)
{
    var mapper = new Mapper(MapperConfiguration());            
    return  mapper.Map<HeadQuarters>(dto);            
}

private static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration()
{
    return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<AdresaDTO, Adresa>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CityId, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.CityId ?? default(int)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HeadQuartersId, act => act.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeId, act => act.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ContractPersonDataId, act => act.Ignore());
        cfg.CreateMap<HeadQuartersDTO, HeadQuarters>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, act => act.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IsActiv, act => act.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Adresa, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Addresses)));
}
```